# quick question about suggested database structure of firebase team

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to develop a chat app. I read official docs of firebase and see this database structure

```
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    // we'll talk about indices like this below
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

**I have a quick question about this structure**

With this structure, when we need to display all conversations , we need to read `chats` node. How can we update the data of `chats` node evertime the last message change ? As I know, we need to attach a listener to `messages` node to get the last message, if so, why dont we just query `limitToLast(1)` to get it and display on a conversations page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create a firebase function (trigger) and listen for every new message in the chat and put it in chats every time a user is sending a message as lastMessage. And yes you can just query the messages by date and get the last one client side.
Maybe you can do it like this:

```
-- chats
---- chatUUID1
------ members
-------- memberUUID1
-------- memberUUID2
-------- ...
------ messages
-------- messageUUID1
---------- messageData
-------- messageUUID2
---------- messageData
-------- ...
---- chatUUID2
---- ...
```

And keep in mind depending on how you create the rules you may need to save the chats a user is participating somewhere for each user or something like this.

Comment: so why we need "Chats" node here. We just need to query on "Messages" node to get the last message and display it as a conversation ?

Comment: See, to get the messages from a chat, you need to know the chatUUID, to get that chatUUID you probably gonna query over members and find all chat keys where you are a member . Depenending on what you are trying to do this structure may not be for you. This example structure is for group chats and probably needs some more nodes to function better. SO basically I don't think you really need "chats" if you dont need a chat title.